# Minimize window to system tray

Tags: windows, sdl-2

I have created a SDL2 application, and would like it to minimize to the system tray, rather than appearing in the task bar.

`SDL_MinimizeWindow` doesn't do what I want, it leaves the task bar icon. Is there a way to achieve this with SDL?

Comment: You are looking for a notification icon. I don't know SDL2, so I don't know if it wraps this. In Win32, you use the `Shell_NotifyIcon` function to manipulate these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no purely SDL2 way to do this, as Cody said, `Shell_NotifyIcon` is the function needed to create a notification area (system tray) icon.

The code I used to get the icon is

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 200, 200, SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);

SDL_SysWMinfo info;
SDL_VERSION(&info.version); 

NOTIFYICONDATA icon;
if (SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &info))
{
    icon.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER + 1;
    icon.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE;
    icon.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    icon.cbSize = sizeof(icon);
    icon.hWnd = info.info.win.window;
    strcpy_s(icon.szTip, "Test tip");

    bool success = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &icon);
}
```

This creates a hidden window, and an icon (using the default information icon).

To interact with this from SDL, you need to enable platform specific window management events, this is done as follows `SDL_EventState(SDL_SYSWMEVENT, SDL_ENABLE);`

After this, in the main event loop you must test for `SDL_SYSWMEVENT`, which contains information about how the user has interacted with the notification area icon. This also looks for the minimize event and hides the window which removes it from the task bar. This is achieved in the following snippet

```
SDL_Event e;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
{
    switch (e.type)
    {
    case SDL_SYSWMEVENT:
        if (e.syswm.msg->msg.win.msg == WM_USER + 1)
        {
            if (LOWORD(e.syswm.msg->msg.win.lParam) == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
            {
                SDL_ShowWindow(window);
                SDL_RestoreWindow(window);
            }
        }
        break;
    case SDL_QUIT:
        running = false;
        break;
    case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
        if (e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED)
            SDL_HideWindow(window);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way was to do the restore at hide time versus show time. I think in SDL3 you can just use SyncWindow to get around the window flag race state. At least for SDL2 Colin's sollution doesn't always work because the hidden window loses its minimize state in a race to change the window properties / flags.

```
NOTIFYICONDATA icon;
if (SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &info))
{
    icon.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER + 1;
    icon.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_MESSAGE;
    icon.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    icon.cbSize = sizeof(icon);
    icon.hWnd = info.info.win.window;
    strcpy_s(icon.szTip, "Test tip");

    bool success = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &icon);
}

bool running = true;

while (!running ) {
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
        case SDL_SYSWMEVENT:
            if (e.syswm.msg->msg.win.msg == WM_USER + 1)
            {
                if (LOWORD(e.syswm.msg->msg.win.lParam) == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
                {
                    SDL_ShowWindow(window);
                    // Alternative available in SDL3 that makes the original 
                    // possible.
                    // SDL_SyncWindow(window);
                    // SDL_RestoreWindow(window);
                }
            }
            break;
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            if (e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED) {
                // Now the window is restored as soon as we show it.
                SDL_RestoreWindow(window);
                // Hide the window.
                SDL_HideWindow(window);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    // Rest of render logic here.
}
```